# UICollectionView Stretchy Header

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Hi everyone I have a collection view with a header I would like it to become a stretchy header when I pull down any ideas how to do this?

[image]

Comment: i think you want like this ? http://www.akpdev.com/articles/2016/06/16/CollectionView-I.html or like this? https://nrj.io/stretchy-uicollectionview-headers/ or like like this https://blog.frozenfirestudios.com/how-to-add-a-stretchy-flair-to-your-uicollectionview-e403822e0f33

Comment: these didn't seem to work out

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll your `UICollectionView` up and down you can be notified when content offset changes. For example using `scrollViewDidScroll`.

If content offset < 0 just change header subview top constraint so it looks like header's top sticks to the top of `UICollectionView`.

```
final class Header: UICollectionReusableView {

    lazy var subview = UIView()
    lazy var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.subview, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(subview)
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
        constraints.append(contentsOf: NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[S]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["S":subview]))
        constraints.append(contentsOf: NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[S]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["S":subview]))
        constraints.append(constraint)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func changed(offset: CGPoint) {
        let constant = offset.y > 0 ? 0 : offset.y
        if constant != constraint.constant {
            constraint.constant = constant
        }
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

I have tested it in playground, but not in a real project. Let me know if it works for you.